# How can one compute the proportion of a country's area that lies within a given distance from the country's border?

Tags: borders, catchment-area

A lawyer friend of mine is preparing a legal argument that concerns the border region of Germany: the part of Germany that is within a given distance (e.g.,  30 km) of the country's border. He needs to know as precisely as feasible what proportion of Germany's total area lies within that border region.
As a person unfamiliar with GIS, I have been unable to find even a hint as to how this proportion might be computed.

I seek any hints, even if they are high-level like "Use function X in software Y" or "Ask company Z to compute it for you".

Comment: This is known as an "Inside" or "Inner" buffer. ArcGIS (the most popular GIS software) and QGIS (a free GIS suite) can both do it pretty easily. You'll need to do a little work determining exactly what your border line is going to be and perhaps editing that source data a little.

Comment: If you get the bounding line for the country polygon in a projected coordinate system then buffer it by 30 metres and intersect the buffer with the country polygon you will end up with just the area within 30 metres of the border, however the area calculation may not be accurate enough... 2d/3d and projection distortion play a part on a polygon the size of a country. What kind of accuracy are you after? Is 30 metres 'as the crow flies' or 'on the ground' distance? (makes a **big** difference in mountain regions).

Comment: @Michael Stimson: There's no exact required level of precision, but the useful suggestions provided here should yield quite adequate precision for our purpose, assuming "as the crow flies" distance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you can buffer the polygon itself. You will need to reproject your administrative area polygon's CRS (as many vector data sets are provided in *EPSG:4326 (WGS84)*, with 'units' in latitude/longitude) into a projection with meters as unit:

- Get a [copy of QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/de/site/forusers/download.html) and the administrative area of germany (maybe [here](http://www.gadm.org/country), in *ESRI Shapefile* format to start with)
- Drag'n'Drop the *.shp* of your downloaded (and extracted if necessary) data/files into QGIS' *Layer Panel*
- Right click on the Layer -> *'Save as...'* -> choose location and (search for) *EPSG:32632* (*WGS84/UTM 32N*) as one possible projection in the *'Target CRS'* field
- Drag'n'Drop the created (and reprojected) file (*.shp*) into the *Layer Panel*
- *Vector* -> *Geoprocessing Tools* -> *Fixed distance buffer* -> enter -30000 (negative) as distance
- *Vector* -> *Geoprocessing Tools* -> *Difference* -> choose your reprojected and the new buffer layer (and specify a location to save if you want it to be a permanent file)

That's a simple workflow to start with and will get you a polygon covering 30km from the outline (border) of the administrative layer 'as the crow flies'.
@Michael Stimson is right, reprojecting the data introduces different precision limitations and actual calculations on that area will be erroneous. For many uses this will suffice though and I think you might want to give it a try if you don´t want to build bridges or sell stuff by the square meter...getting more precise and maybe even with true ground distance will increase your efforts exponentially...

**EDIT:**
You might want to use ***EPSG:3035 (ETRS89 / ETRS-LAEA)*** in the above steps instead, being an equal area projection basically centered on Germany, with minimized projection distortions when dealing with area calculations (I just now realized I didn´t propose this projection in my initial answer as I was intending, *EPSG:32632* has become quite a habit...).

Comment: Perhaps I missed it in the proposed workflow, but won't this yield the opisite of what was asked for? Won't this produce a shape that represents all the area NOT within 30km of the border? I can see as a next step executing a union of this negative buffer and the original border shape to calculate the relative proportions of the two areas.

Comment: @Zipper2365 The final difference step identifies the part **not** in the negative buffer. There are a number of potential paths to the same result, including converting perimeter to line, buffering and intersecting.

Comment: @Zipper1365 What I did leave out is the actual (asked for) proportion calculation. Here's a thought (which might lead to another question if not someone elaborate on this a little more as I am not sure): if you have a (distorted) polygon (borders), and a directly derived one  (30km band, equally distorted), could an areal proportion (percentage of total area) actually yield proper results?

Comment: By distorted, do you mean in an inappropriate projection that does not adequately optimize area accuracy or do you mean low resolution?  Both scenarios have drawbacks, but I would rather work with low resolution data than stuff that's not projected right - especially for an entire country like this.  Even though the negative buffer would be distorted (read "wrong") just like the input, on the scale of an entire country, a 30km distance might not measure out proportionally when we're working with things of this size depending on the projection.